# scanf stops taking inputs from the commandline once you feed into it (the command line) an input that it didn't expect

Tags: c, io, scanf, inputstream

Here's my code. When it asked for my first input on the command line, I entered '5cde'. Then it printed '5', and it didn't ask for any more inputs before termination.

How is this okay? Is there a way to see how scanf is working internally as I run this program? I really want to know what exactly is going on behind the scenes. I'm not sure how the input buffer works, and if I should even be messing with it. Or should I just use a different io function instead? Because scanf seems pretty unsafe to me.

```
int i;

scanf("%d", &i);
printf("%d", i);
scanf("%d", &i);
scanf("%d", &i);
scanf("%d", &i);
scanf("%d", &i);
```

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the function `scanf` when the conversion specifier d is used is the following

> **d** Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function
> with the value 10 for the base argument. The corresponding argument
> shall be a pointer to signed integer

So for this input buffer

```
5cde
```

the first call of `scanf` reads the character `5` because it represents a valid integer number and the position in the input buffer moves to the right to the character `'c'`.

When the next and subsequent calls of `scanf` failed because the symbol `'c'` is not a valid digit. The position in the input stream stays the same.

You should check whether call of `scanf` was successful> For example

```
if ( scanf("%d", &i) == 1 )
{
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
else
{
    // remove the invalid input
    scanf( "%*[^\n]%*c" );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { N = 3 };
    
    printf( "Enter %d numbers.", N );
    
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "\t%d: ", i + 1 );
        int value;
        
        while ( !( scanf( "%d", &value ) == 1 ) )
        {
            scanf( "%*[^\n]%*c" );
            puts( "Invalid input. Try again" );
            printf( "\t%d: ", i + 1 );
        }
        
        printf( "You inputted %d\n", value );
    }
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter 3 numbers.
    1: 1A
You inputted 1
    2: 
Invalid input. Try again
    2: B 
Invalid input. Try again
    2: 2C
You inputted 2
    3: 
Invalid input. Try again
    3: 3
You inputted 3
```

That is the user entered the following sequence of strings

```
1A
B
2C
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the result of each `scanf` call. It returns the number of items successfully read (or EOF in case of failure) so in your case it should return `1` or otherwise something went wrong.

Please also note that each time you hit enter during input, there's a trailing line feed character added to  `stdin` which needs to be discarded, if you were for example to read a string after reading a number. This should be addressed early on in your C book, if it's any good.

Overall `scanf` is to be regarded as a quick & dirty function for simplistic programs and not something to be used in real production code, so you don't really need to worry about leaning all the details of it. Using `fgets` and reading everything as strings is much better (and faster) practice.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you ask for input, the user will also press Enter.

Therefore, get input as a string, *then* turn that string into a number. As there are several steps to reading a number and verifying it as correct, you can even write a convenient function to help.

```
void fatal_error( const char * message )
{
  fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", message );
  exit( 1 );
}

int get_int( const char * prompt, int min, int max, const char * error_message )
{
  char s[ 100 ];
  int n, count;

  printf( "%s ", prompt );
  fflush( stdout );

  if (   !fgets( s, sizeof(s), stdin )             // user's input
      or (sscanf_s( s, "%d %n", &n, &count ) != 1) // convert to int
      or (count != strlen( s ))                    // no "123abc" stuff allowed
      or (n < min)
      or (n > max) )
    fatal_error( error_message );

  return n;
}

int main()
{
  int n = ask_int( "n?", 1, 100, "n is not optional, and must be in [1,100]" );
  int age = ask_int( "How old are you?", 0, INT_MAX, "You cannot be negative years old." );

  etc
```